# How to Highlight the Menu in css. I used a:active but it does not serve the purpose I expected

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

.cshtml

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Tools", "Index", new { Area = "", Controller = "Tools" })</li>
```

.css

```
a:active
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #F96611;
    border: 3px solid #FFB380;
}
```

a:active works only between mouse click press and release. But I need the **menu** to be in **highlighted** after the mouse click of a menu. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant add in css. .active applies for click only but not for active state. you can use the below jquery code for adding class on click

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('youractiveclass'); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

after the mouse click of a menu , it becomes "visited"
you should add this to your css :

```
a:visited
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #F96611;
    border: 3px solid #FFB380;
}
```

also there you can do it for *a.hover* and *a.link*

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with CSS (using `visited`). The CSS `active` pseudo-class applies only for the duration of the click, not afterwards. If you want a lasting effect, use `visited`, or better, Javascript. Through javascript you can also customize it so that the style is added or removed with alternate clicks:

```
$("#menu").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('highlightclass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Active state works only while you holds on mouse button on a link. That's how it's supposed to be.

Check this fiddle to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/8fqGp/

If you want to persistently highlight the menu item, you should follow Sowmya's or Cupidvogel's answer.